# Regex Search().groups() returns partial list values Python

Tags: python, regex, tags

I have a list of tags such as:

```
 <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2709069">Roaming to other network when yours is unavailable</a>,
 <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2747612">Wifi Calling problem</a>,
 <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2705042">Kogan Mobile non-compliance with Tax Invoices</a>,
 <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2715307">please help internet god</a>,
 <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2715014">Apple deals returning soon?</a>
```

The following regex search function can pull out all 101 matches when just running:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(?<=>)(\w|\d|\s)+')
ThreadNames = []
for string in ThreadNameFlat:
    ThreadNames.append(re.search(regex,str(string)))
```

when i try to run the next group of code to just grab the match by itself, `ThreadNames` only returns 10 of the full 101 matches the above code returns with and `ThreadNamesTest` returns singular matches such as `'m','','n'` etc...

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(?<=>)(\w|\d|\s)+')
ThreadNames = []
ThreadNamesTest = []
for string in ThreadNameFlat:
    ThreadNames.append(re.search(regex,str(string)))
    match = re.search(regex,str(string))
    ThreadNamesTest.append(match.groups())
```

It appears the `groups()` function is causing the issue, even though i thought that `groups()` should return all 101 matches originally found in the first script.

EDIT: I changed it to `.group()` instead of `.groups()` and now it is returning 10/101 tags with the full match.

How can i get all 10 out of the 101 tags though?

[The new result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf1Dm.png)

Comment: Your capturing group `(\w|\d|\s)` will capture a single character. To start with, sounds like you want a non-capturing group instead. Or, you might consider repeating anything but a `<` with a negated character set. Or, you might consider using a proper HTML parser instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance but shouldn't groups() return the entire match as the first group of code returns all 101 matches in their full length?

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output .

Answer (score 0):

`re.search` returns a `Match` object. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). As for `Match.groups`:

> Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern.

But you don't care about the subgroups here - you just want the *full match*. For that, you should probably use [`.group()` or `.group(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group):

> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned).

Like this:

```
import re
ThreadNameFlat = ['<a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2709069">Roaming to other network when yours is unavailable</a>',
' <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2747612">Wifi Calling problem</a>',
' <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2705042">Kogan Mobile non-compliance with Tax Invoices</a>',
' <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2715307">please help internet god</a>',
' <a class="title" href="/forum-replies.cfm?t=2715014">Apple deals returning soon?</a>']

regex = re.compile('(?<=>)(?:\w|\d|\s)+')
ThreadNamesTest = []
for string in ThreadNameFlat:
    match = re.search(regex,str(string))
    ThreadNamesTest.append(match.group())
print(ThreadNamesTest)
```

Output:

```
['Roaming to other network when yours is unavailable', 'Wifi Calling problem', 'Kogan Mobile non', 'please help internet god', 'Apple deals returning soon']
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The regex did not match anything on the 11th value of the tag list.
`.group()` then fails to pick up the following matches after it does not find anything on the 11th value.

Changed the regex from:

```
regex = re.compile('(?<=>)(\w|\d|\s)+')
```

to:

```
regex = re.compile('(?<=>)(.\w.|.\s)+')
```

which will matches any character except line breaks, which not picks up the random encoded value in the 11th tag.